# How to handle handshake_failure in java

Tags: java, ssl

I have problem with one site. My case :
I have to send request to site with POST method but it throws exception :

```
I/O error on POST request for "https://xxx": Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Is it possible to handle it without migrate certifikate ?

I already tried to disable trustmanager with :

```
private void disableSSL() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        TrustManager[] trustManager = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };
        final SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustManager, null);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    }
```

but it doesnt helps.

```
10:08:34,405 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) trigger seeding of SecureRandom
10:08:34,408 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) done seeding SecureRandom
10:08:39,102 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
10:08:39,104 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Allow legacy hello messages: true
10:08:39,106 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Is initial handshake: true
10:08:39,107 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Is secure renegotiation: false
10:08:39,112 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) default task-6, setSoTimeout(60000) called
10:08:39,112 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) default task-6, the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=xxx) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=xxx)
10:08:39,121 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
10:08:39,125 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
10:08:39,126 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
10:08:39,126 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
10:08:39,126 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
10:08:39,137 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
10:08:39,140 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
10:08:39,142 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
10:08:39,142 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
10:08:39,151 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
10:08:39,153 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
10:08:39,157 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
10:08:39,158 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
10:08:39,158 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
10:08:39,187 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) %% No cached client session
10:08:39,192 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
10:08:39,322 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) RandomCookie:  GMT: 1610530567 bytes = { 159, 16, 224, 148, 174, 109, 10, 138, 121, 232, 250, 113, 170, 208, 75, 92, 107, 214, 49, 28, 201, 243, 230, 244, 202, 241, 179, 88 }
10:08:39,325 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Session ID:  {}
10:08:39,325 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
10:08:39,340 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Compression Methods:  { 0 }
10:08:39,341 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
10:08:39,341 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
10:08:39,349 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
10:08:39,351 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=staging.crossborder.omniship.eu]
10:08:39,355 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) ***
10:08:39,355 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) default task-6, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 201
10:08:39,403 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) default task-6, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
10:08:39,423 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) default task-6, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
10:08:39,425 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) default task-6, called closeSocket()
10:08:39,429 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) default task-6, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I can't restart jvm. I just need to handle this request.

Problem occurs on java 1.8_0_151. On java 1.8_0_181 everything is ok.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It would help to find a reason for the  `handshake_failure` message. Based on your action it's an untrusted CA, but there may be different reasons , such as mismatched ciphersuit, no client certificate, ....  so you need to find out more than just a single line. Try to verbose the handshake `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose`

Comment: The server mentioned in the log only supports TLS1.2 & TLS 1.3 and a very limited number of ciphers (only TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_...) . Java 8 only supports TLS 1.2 and on Linux there are often problems with ECDSA. Not sure what causes those problems, may be other libraries are required on Linux. You can try to add BouncyCastle provider to your application. And please immediately remove that accept-all trustmanager, this sort of code should never be used even not for a staging server.